# Export excel table (and graph) as image (linux, php, python, anything...)

Tags: excel, image, export, screenshot

maybe I will have luck here. 
I have crazy idea. In order to automatize things at work, I would like to know if there is any possibility to create screenshot or image from excel file using script and then send it somewhere. I dont know whether it is possible using Php, or python, or whatever running on Linux.

If you have working solution on Windows - feel free to post it.
And no, I could not found any possible solution on the internet.

Comment: Get back to internet and search `Range.CopyPicture` and `Chart.Export` and of course `VBA`

Comment: Thank you ! :) Range.CopyPicture is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about taking a screen shot but you can always simply duplicate the excel spreadsheet file and sent it as an attachment to an email address you choose (ie change the '.To' file below).  If you have Outlook installed on your machine the following should work.  It will append the date to the spreadsheet filename before sending it.  You'll of course have to go into the macro and change the settings - but you can always use VBA to create a form prompting you for the necessary information:

```
Sub send_worksheet()
  Dim xFile As String
  Dim xFormat As Long
  Dim Wb As Workbook
  Dim Wb2 As Workbook
  Dim FilePath As String
  Dim FileName As String
  Dim OutlookApp As Object
  Dim OutlookMail As Object
  On Error Resume Next

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set Wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
  ActiveSheet.Copy
  Set Wb2 = Application.ActiveWorkbook

  Select Case Wb.FileFormat
    Case xlOpenXMLWorkbook:
      xFile = ".xlsx"
      xFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    Case xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled:
      If Wb2.HasVBProject Then
         xFile = ".xlsm"
         xFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
      Else
         xFile = ".xlsx"
         xFormat = xlOpenXMLWorkbook
      End If
   Case Excel8:
      xFile = ".xls"
      xFormat = Excel8
   Case xlExcel12:
      xFile = ".xlsb"
      xFormat = xlExcel12
  End Select

  FilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
  FileName = Wb.Name & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
  Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  Set OutlookMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)

  Wb2.SaveAs FilePath & FileName & xFile, FileFormat:=xFormat

  With OutlookMail
     .To = "email.account@gmail.com"
     .CC = ""
     .BCC = ""
     .Subject = "Example of Spreadsheet sent via email"
     .Body = "See the attached spreadsheet."
     .Attachments.Add Wb2.FullName
     .Send
  End With

  Wb2.Close

  Kill FilePath & FileName & xFile
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```